# Having issues with sequence in mysql database using Springboot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying persist data into MySQL using hibernate in SpringBoot. I am having an issue with id values not autogenerating in sequence. I am using @onetomany relationship and joining columns.

```
[
    {
        "customerId": 1,
        "firstName": "tom",
        "lastName": "jerry",
        "savingAccount": [
            {
                "savingId": 3, <----- first saving account. value should be 1. 
                "balance": 100,
                "newBalance": 100,
                "customerId": 1,
                "addorMinusBalance": 100
            }
        ],
        "checkingAccount": [
            {
                "checkingId": 2,   <----- first checking account. value should be 1. 
                "balance": 1900,
                "addOrMinusBalance": 1900,
                "newBalance": 1900,
                "customerId": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My code for the entity classes:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="checking_id")
    private Integer checkingId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="saving_id")
    private Integer savingId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't having an issue with the sequence you have an issue with your understanding what sequences are for. Sequences guarantee uniqueness of generated ids. They might not be out of order or they have gaps. And since they are mostly intended for generating technical ids, this should be perfectly fine.

If that doesn't work for you, you need to assign the values manually and apply whatever logic you need. Note that many of the typical requirements for sequences, like no gaps are only possible with some severe locking limiting the performance and throughput of your application. Also, such a field shouldn't be an id, because it isn't an id.